# How to put a countdown in a table using asp.net code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Let's say I have a table called adverts with the following fields: `advert_id`, `name`,`date_created description`, `duration`, `status`, `user_id`, `cat_id`.

Let's say a user puts a duration of 1 week in the duration field and its status is set to active. After a week has passed, the status is set to inactive in the table.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to do this with asp.net 4.0 code using visual basic in visual studio 2010 with web forms?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to update a status at all.  Instead of (or in addition to) duration, store the datetime the status is to be set to active (current datetime plus duration).  The application can then consider values less than the current datetime as active without having to actually update the row.

If desired, you can still derive the active status as a column the query or as a derived column in the table.  For example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN active_date <= GETDATE() THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS active
FROM dbo.adverts;
```